# How can I understand aggregation and containment?

Tags: c#, object-oriented

I'm confused between aggregation and containment. I'm wondering if the following represent an aggregation or containment?

```
class Auto 
{

   private string model;
   private int speed;

     class AutoCustomer
     {
        public string LastName;
        public string Address;
        public DateTime DateOfPurchase;
     }
}
```

Comment: This is a [nested class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120), which (at least in your code) has nothing to do with aggregation or containment. Also, did you mean “composition” instead of “containment”?

Comment: @svick [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Containment) shows both as varieties of composition

Comment: A block of concrete is an *aggregation* of cement and gravel. A bowl is a *container* of fruit. An auto is not *made out of* customers, and does not *contain* customers, so the answer to your question is "no". It is an example of neither.

Answer (score 1):

The way to understand aggregation versus containment is association versus ownership. Does a car "have" an engine? Yes, it wouldn't be a car without it (in most situations). Does a fruit bowl "have" fruit? Yes; even if there are currently zero fruit in the bowl.

Does a car "have" a customer? No. The dealership "has" a customer—maybe—and the dealership "has" cars. The dealership may wish to *associate* a customer with a car they're interested in, but the car doesn't own that customer.

Answer (score 1):

A good litmus test for aggregation vs. composition is asking yourself if you would delete the child-object when you delete the parent-object.

When you don't need the Auto anymore, do you still need the AutoCustomer it references? When you do, you have a case of aggregation. When you don't need it, you have a case of composition.

Answer (score 0):

If your class `Auto` is going to have a reference to the class `AutoCustomer`, then this represents an example of [Aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Containment), since the `Auto` class doesnt OWN the `AutoCustomer` instance.

But it is sketchy.. since the data members of `AutoCustomer` are so specific that it might imply ownership after all, which means its just vanilla composition.